# Android TextInputEditText doesn't focus on cursor position

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

When trying to edit long text inside `TextInputEditText`, the focus goes always to the bottom, so the top (where actually the cursor is) stays out of the screen and you cannot see actually what you are typing. See a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLncD.gif) showing the `TextInputEditText` problem that I describe.

My xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Notes"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Notes"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Material library version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

Comment: Have you tried setting max lines to it?

Comment: I just tried android:maxLines="100" but it didn't help.

Comment: 100 is too many. Why not try limiting it to 10 or something?

Comment: I would like to avoid having a limit for lines. Clearly reducing the maxLines would make the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/a8d8e70d898e61a190f0fc64eae298a713fbbdb8) so using the latest beta release seems to be working just fine:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-beta01'
```